How can i update and insert new values in RSQlite?
I have a SQLite database which i want to fill using the RSQlite Interface. Some rows need to be updated and some rows need to be added. So using dbWriteTable() is neither sufficient with the option overwrite = TRUE nor with the option append = TRUE. What I tried instead is the following approach:


df_1 <- tibble::tibble(
  
  a = as.character(c(rep("a", 48), rep("b", 48))),
  b = as.character(c(rep("2024-12-04", 48), rep("2024-12-05", 48))),
  c = as.character(rep(seq(as.POSIXct("2024-12-04 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2024-12-05 23:00:00"), by="hour"), 2)),
  d = as.numeric(c(rep(12.5, 48), rep(13.5, 48)))
  
)


df_2 <- tibble::tibble(
  
  a = as.character(c(rep("a", 24))),
  b = as.character(c(rep("2024-12-04", 24))),
  c = as.character(seq(as.POSIXct("2024-12-04 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2024-12-04 23:00:00"), by="hour")),
  d = as.numeric(c(rep(5, 24)))
)

df_3 <- tibble::tibble(
  
  a = as.character(c(rep("a", 24), rep("b", 24), rep("c", 24))),
  b = as.character(c(rep("2024-12-04", 24), rep("2024-12-05", 24), rep("2024-12-06", 24))),
  c = as.character(seq(as.POSIXct("2024-12-04 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2024-12-06 23:00:00"), by="hour")),
  d = as.numeric(c(rep(1, 24), rep(2, 24), rep(3, 24)))

)  


con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")



dbExecute(con, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS df_test
          
          (
          
          a TEXT,
          b TEXT,
          c TEXT, 
          d REAL
          )
          
          ")

dbListTables(con)

dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM df_test")

df_test <- dplyr::tbl(con, "df_test")

df_update <- dbplyr::copy_inline(con,
                            df_1)

dplyr::rows_upsert(df_test, df_update, by = c("a", "b", "c"), in_place = TRUE)

dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM df_test")

dbDisconnect(con)


When i run rows_upsert() i get the following error:
Error in `dplyr::rows_upsert()`:
! Can't modify database table "df_test".

...


Caused by error:
! ON CONFLICT clause does not match any PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint

Contrasting to my minimal reproducible example the database is not in memory but on hard drive.
Originally i exported the table from the database, used upsert_rows() with in_place = FALSE and dbWriteTable() with overwrite = TRUE. This approach works but is not operable due to the large scale of the dataset (up to 500 million rows). I lose a lot of time waiting that the query is completed and potentially i will run into memory issues.
Is there any other solution to edit the database directly from RStudio?

If i add a suitable primary key it works.

https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/rows.html reads: "rows_upsert() inserts or updates depending on whether or not the key value in y already exists in x. Key values in y must be unique." this suggests a primary key is required.
